# Subplots with multiple spectral.imshow() objec

Tags: loops, subplot, imshow, spectral-python

I want to plot multiple hyperspectral images with sp.imshow. I know this returns a R,G,B visualization. I have 13 HSI files (13 .hdr and 13 .img files). I know how to plot and analyze individual files but I want an overview of all my samples in a grid.

I am also aware of creating the fig, axes previously. Yet subplots are still confusing.
This is what I have so far.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import spectral as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

files_path = Path(r"C:\data\Reflectance_Calibrated")
hdr_list = list(files_path.glob('*.hdr'))
bin_list = list(files_path.glob('*.img'))

targets = list(zip(hdr_list,bin_list))

i = 0

## Here is where I tried doing a for loop, yet it did not work.

for k, target in enumerate(targets):
    target_open = sp.envi.open(targets[i][0], targets[i][1])
    sp.imshow(target_open)
    i += 1
```

I am looking for something like `sp.imshow(target_open).add_subplot(ax)`

Has anyone tried doing subplots with spectral.imshow objects?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to achieve what you want. One is to use `plt.subplot` to select each grid cell, then when you call `sp.imshow`, pass the `fignum` keyword. For example, to create an Nx1 grid of images (i.e., a grid with a single column):

```
fig = plt.figure()
for k, target in enumerate(targets):
    target_open = sp.envi.open(targets[k][0], targets[k][1])
    plt.subplot(len(targets), 1, k + 1)
    sp.imshow(target_open, fignum=fig.number)
```

Another option is to use `sp.get_rgb` to retrieve the RGB image data for each image, then use `plt.imshow` to do the rendering instead of `sp.imshow`.

Comment: Thanks, this does iterate and plot all my samples thanks! Yet even changing the subplot(len(targets), 2, k +1) axes are on top of each other. Tried squeeze, sharex=True, and modifying fig size but did not work.

Comment: I don't follow the comment about axes being on top of each other. Also, if you change the number of columns to 2 (as in your comment), then you'll probably wan to change the third arg to `plt.subplot` as well, since it is simply counting grid cells as a flat index (starting at 1) in row major order.